# MongoDB 3.4 Map Reduce and Decimal128

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, decimal

Is it possible to accumulate a field of the new decimal type using map reduce in mongo 3.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript does not have support for arithmetic with the `Decimal128` type added in MongoDB 3.4 so you cannot accumulate these decimal values in Map/Reduce functions. One of the general limitations of JavaScript is that it only has a single native numeric type of `Number` [(64-bit double-precision binary)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Number_type).

However, `Decimal128` values **are** supported by the aggregation framework's [arithmetic expressions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#arithmetic-expressions) and [accumulators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#accumulators).

In general the aggregation framework is more recommendable in terms of efficiency and performance. Map/Reduce processing involves converting data between the underlying storage representation (BSON) and JavaScript; the aggregation framework is implemented with C++ and can manipulate BSON objects directly.

Comment: Thanks.  I had pretty much come to the same conclusion.  I appreciate the confirmation.  I was able to accomplish what I needed using the aggregation pipeline.  Thanks again!